# Moment.js difference between flight departure and arrival

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

var departure = moment.tz("2015-06-17T15:03:00.000", "America/Los_Angeles");
console.log("departure: " + departure.utc().format());
var arrival = moment.tz("2015-06-18T20:05:00.000", "Asia/Hong_Kong");
console.log("arrival: " + arrival.utc().format());

departureUTC = departure.utc();
arrivalUTC = arrival.utc();

var duration = moment(arrival.diff(departure)).format("h:mm");
console.log(duration);

var durationUTC = moment(arrivalUTC.diff(departureUTC)).format("h:mm");
console.log(durationUTC);
```

Both of these options are producing a duration of 9:02 rather than 14:02 (the correct duration).  A simple mistake, I am sure, but cannot see it.

Comment: The timezone difference is 15 hours. So 3am in LA is 18pm in HK. That means the flight takes 11 hours? Not 9 or 14.

Comment: It takes 14 hours because it is not 3am but 3pm ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `moment.duration` to deal with durations here.

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

var departure = moment.tz("2015-06-17T15:03:00.000", "America/Los_Angeles");
console.log("departure: " + departure.utc().format());
var arrival = moment.tz("2015-06-18T20:05:00.000", "Asia/Hong_Kong");
console.log("arrival: " + arrival.utc().format());

var duration = moment.duration(arrival.diff(departure));
console.log("duration: " + duration.humanize());
```

Comment: That works great!  I'm trying to get the format `"h:mm"`, but `format("h:mm")` is not a function on the duration object.  Using `toJSON()` spits out `PT14H2M` but I am not sure what to do with that.

Comment: You will have to use a plugin because durations are fundamentally different from dates : https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format